# Suggested short-cuts for "Command" shortcuts used across most programs

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, macos

I often find myself using the following no matter what the program is:

- `Cmd` `s` to save.
- `Cmd` `a` to select-all
- `Cmd` `t` to open a new tab
- `Cmd` `c` to copy
- `Cmd` `v` to paste
- `Cmd` `z` to undo
- `Cmd` `Shift` z to redo

That how it works in most computers, regardless of what mode I'm in or whatever. What would be a good keyboard mapping I can use in `vim` to do something similar? I don't believe `cmd` is supposed (without doing some odd mapping).

I also am not a big fan of using `ctrl` as I often use that in other programs to advance to the start of a line `ctrl` `a` or advance to the end of the line `ctrl` `e`, and I'm already familiar with `ctrl` `v` for visual mode.

What might be a good mapping where I can do something that might feel close to doing the `cmd`-`letter` input, i.e. and it will work across all modes (that is, I should be able to select-all whether I'm in normal mode or insert mode)? Additionally, if useful, I'm using vim on mac and (mainly) ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using vim as a GUI (i.e. MacVim or another GVim) or in the terminal? It's easy to write mappings for all these in a GUI version of Vim, but much harder in a terminal as they typically don't pass them through... If you use it in a terminal, what terminal emulator do you use (iTerm2, Terminal.app, etc.)?

Comment: This question had 3 close votes for being opinion-based. Is it because the OP said "What might be a good mapping..."? Would the question have been received better if the OP had simply said "How can I..."?

Comment: For future reference, Vim questions can be asked on [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing [MacVim](https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/) which already comes with many (all?) of these keybindings set as default.

Within MacVim, I found I could use `<D-key>` in mappings, to capture <kbd>Cmd-key</kbd> presses.

For example:

```
# Undo and redo
nnoremap <D-Z> u
nnoremap <D-S-Z> <C-R>
# Navigate back and forwards
nnoremap <D-[> <C-O>
nnoremap <D-]> <C-I>
```

I don't know if these will work for vim in a terminal.  They might.